# How to move the button 'submit' down the div '.content2' in the output?

Tags: html, css

How to move the button 'submit' down the div '.content2' in [this](http://jsbin.com/hicefu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) example?
As shown in the html pane, I set them in the desired order. However; when the div shows up, it doesn't shift the button down.

```
switch fade slide alert

[taken space by div ]

submit
```

Comment: Because it *is* below the button in DOM. absolute positioning removes the element from normal flow, but it doesn't change the position of the element unless `top`, `left`, ... offsets are set.

Comment: No, it isn't. In html, the div is located above the button "submit".

Comment: Okay, I rephrase my comment. It is not under "submit" button, but under the other buttons preceded by the "submit" button. So, the only thing happens when you position the middle `div` absolutely, is that the element is removed from normal flow and and therefore the "submit" button is placed beside the other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Because `position:absolute` requieres coordenates to position (top, left, right...) If you don't use it, even if it's out of the html flow, his position will be the one that it would be if static or relative position. (and it may change depending on browsers.)